# typecast classes in python: how?

Tags: python, class, oop

Here, I am attempting to mock up a social media profile as a class "Profile", in which you have name, a group of friends, and the ability to add and remove friends.  There is a method that I would like to make, that when invoked, will print the list of friends in alphabetical order.

The issue: I get a warning that I cannot sort an unsortable type.  Python is seeing my instance variable as a "Profile object", rather than a list that I can sort and print.

Here is my code:

```
class Profile(object):
    """
    Represent a person's social profile

    Argument:
    name (string): a person's name - assumed to uniquely identify a person

    Attributes:
    name (string): a person's name - assumed to uniquely identify a person
    statuses (list): a list containing a person's statuses - initialized to []
    friends (set): set of friends for the given person.
                   it is the set of profile objects representing these friends.
    """

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.friends = set()
        self.statuses = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " is " + self.get_last_status()

    def update_status(self, status):
        self.statuses.append(status)
        return self

    def get_last_status(self):
        if len(self.statuses) == 0:
            return "None"
        else:
            return self.statuses[-1]

    def add_friend(self, friend_profile):
        self.friends.add(friend_profile)
        friend_profile.friends.add(self)
        return self

    def get_friends(self):
        if len(self.friends) == 0:
            return "None"
        else:
            friends_lst = list(self.friends)
            return sorted(friends_lst)
```

After I fill out a list of friends (from a test module) and invoke the get_friends method, python tells me:

```
 File "/home/tjm/Documents/CS021/social.py", line 84, in get_friends
    return sorted(friends_lst)
TypeError: unorderable types: Profile() < Profile()
```

Why can't I simply typecast the object to get it in list form?  What should I be doing instead so that get_friends will return an alphabetically sorted list of friends?

Comment: Simple solution: `return sorted(friends_lst, key=lambda x:x.name)`

Comment: aside, `list([])` and `set({})` are redundant, `[]` and `set()` are sufficient

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary i am using python3 indeed. your suggestion above still prints the objects and their location in memory, rather than the lists. why is this so?

Comment: @ThomasMatthew Because you've not defined `__repr__` method. Containers like list, tuple, dict etc usually show the `repr(`) version of the object.

Comment: @ThomasMatthew Also as IfLoop pointed out, don't confuse `{}` with a set. This is a very common mistake, to get an empty set use `set()`. Though `set({})` works but that's not the right way.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary can you show me how to define the `__repr__` method?  classes are new to me, and the examples i've seen for the that method do not make sense to me.

Comment: @ThomasMatthew Same way you've defined `__str__`, or simply rename `__str__` to `__repr__`. `str()` calls fallback to `__repr__` if `__str__` is not defined. http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr and https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary for some reason the `__repr__' definition isn't giving me what i'm looking for.  looks like i'll have to read through those docs you posted.  thank you for linking those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i'll take a crack at this.  first, here's teh codes:

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Profile(namedtuple("Profile", "name")):
    def __init__(self, name):
        # don't set self.name, it's already set!
        self.friends = set({})
        self.statuses = list([])

    # ... and all the rest the same.  Only the base class changes.
```

what we've done here is to create a class with the *shape* of a tuple.  As such, it's orderable, hashable, and all of the things.   You could even drop your `__str__()` method, `namedtuple` provides a nice one.

Comment: this gives me an output that is very close to what i wanted.  thank you!  there is a KeyError: Profile(name='Bob'), which is odd.  does this mean that bob is trying to be removed from a profile that he isn't friends with?

Answer (score 6):

Sorting algorithms look for the existence of `__eq__`, `__ne__`, `__lt__`, `__le__`, `__gt__`,`__ge__` methods in the class definition to compare instances created from them. You need to override those methods in order to tweak their behaviors.

For performance reasons, I'd recommend you to define some `integer` property for your class like `id` and use it for comparing instead of `name` which has string comparison overhead.

```
class Profile(object):
    def __eq__(self, profile):
        return self.id == profile.id # I made it up the id property.

    def __lt__(self, profile):
        return self.id < profile.id

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.id)

    ...
```

Alternatively, you can pass a `key` function to sort algorithm if you don't want to bother yourself overriding those methods:

```
>>> friend_list = [<Profile: id=120>, <Profile: id=121>, <Profile: id=115>]
>>> friend_list.sort(key=lambda p: p.id, reverse=True)
```

Using `operator.attrgetter`;

```
>>> import operator
>>> new_friend_list = sorted(friend_list, key=operator.attrgetter('id'))
```

Comment: @Cthulhu OP is clearly using Python 3 where `__cmp__` is not available anymore.

Comment: Note that this solution won't work because now the instances are not hashable anymore, hence the following lines `self.friends.add(friend_profile);friend_profile.friends.add(self)` will raise error.

Comment: @ozgur thank you for offering up so many alternatives to my problem, and for introducing me to the operator module.  looks like i have some reading to do.  thanks again